# Efficiently summarize data over many different time periods by additional criteria (person and location) in R

Tags: r, performance, dplyr, data.table

I have pollution measures by day and location. I have a population of people for which I want to measure pollution exposure. Each person has a location and a period of time during which they were in that location.

For each person in my dataset, I need to sum up the pollution values from their location over their time period, and also count the number of missing pollution measurements.

The table structures are the following:

```
  ids start_dates  end_dates  zips
1   1  2000-10-10 2001-02-18 45108
2   2  2000-11-11 2001-04-07 45190
3   3  2000-03-05 2000-06-27 45117
4   4  2001-02-04 2001-06-09 45142
5   5  2000-03-16 2000-07-13 45197
6   6  1999-12-15 2000-04-27 45060
```

```
  exposure_day exposure_zip exposure_value
1   1999-06-26        45108             14
2   1999-06-27        45108             27
3   1999-06-28        45108             22
4   1999-06-29        45108              4
5   1999-06-30        45108             26
6   1999-07-01        45108             20
```

Desired output:

```
   ids start_dates  end_dates  zips exposure_sum na_count
1:   1  2000-10-10 2001-02-18 45108         3188        5
2:   2  2000-11-11 2001-04-07 45190         3789        1
3:   3  2000-03-05 2000-06-27 45117         2917        3
4:   4  2001-02-04 2001-06-09 45142         2969        2
5:   5  2000-03-16 2000-07-13 45197         2860        3
6:   6  1999-12-15 2000-04-27 45060         3497        2
```

**My current solution is quite slow.** I would like to find a more efficient solution, so that I can efficiently perform this calculation for roughly 1,000,000 people.

Below is the code to simulate my data and my current solution.

```
set.seed(123)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

# Make person dataframe
n = 1000  # sample size
ids = c(1:n)
end_dates = sample(seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'), as.Date('2002-01-01'), by="day"), n, replace = T)
time_intervals = sample(seq(100, 200), n, replace = T)
start_dates = end_dates - time_intervals
zips = sample(seq(45000, 45200), n, replace = T)

person_df = data.frame(ids, start_dates, end_dates,  zips)

# Make exposure dataframe
ziplist = unique(zips)
nzips = length(ziplist)
ndays = as.numeric(as.Date(max(person_df$end_dates)) - as.Date(min(person_df$start_dates)) + 1)
exposure_dates = seq(as.Date(min(person_df$start_dates)), as.Date(max(person_df$end_dates)), by = 'day')
exposure_day = rep(exposure_dates, nzips)
exposure_zip = rep(ziplist, each = ndays)
exposure_value = sample(c(NA, 1:50), length(exposure_day), replace = T)

exposure_df = data.frame(exposure_day, exposure_zip, exposure_value)

# convert to datatable
person_dt = data.table(person_df)
exposure_dt = data.table(exposure_df) 

#summarize
summary_dt = person_dt[, ":="(exposure_sum = .(sum(exposure_dt[exposure_day>=start_dates & exposure_day<=end_dates & exposure_zip == zips, exposure_value], na.rm = T)),
                                na_count =    .(sum(is.na(exposure_dt[exposure_day>=start_dates & exposure_day<=end_dates & exposure_zip == zips, exposure_value])))),
                        by = 'ids'][]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT --- added variation of @langtang's clever approach, which allows an n=1M approach in 4 seconds with dplyr.

---

This dplyr approach is about 40x faster at n=1000, 50x at n=10k, and 60x faster at n=100k, with the same output. The main gain is from translating the non-equi join into a left join by expanding `person_df` to have one row for each `exposure_day` in each `ids` range. That upfront step of expanding all the dates can be done once to make the subsequent joins dramatically faster.

It takes about 2 minutes when I run this for n=1,000,000, which I presume would take around 2 hours using the original code. I imagine further improvements could be made by porting to `data.table` or `collapse` if that isn't fast enough.

```
person_df %>% 
  group_by(ids, exposure_zip = zips) %>%
  summarize(exposure_day = seq.Date(start_dates, end_dates, by = "day"), .groups = "drop") %>%
  left_join(exposure_df) %>%
  group_by(ids) %>%
  summarize(exposure_sum = sum(exposure_value, na.rm = TRUE),
            na_count = sum(is.na(exposure_value))) %>%
  # optional to add start dates end dates, zips columns back
  left_join(person_df)
```

---

Update: porting to `data.table` using `dtplyr` improved the 1M row test slightly, to 100 seconds on my machine.

```
library(dtplyr)
person_df %>%
  lazy_dt() %>%
  group_by(ids, exposure_zip = zips) %>%
  summarize(exposure_day = seq.Date(start_dates, end_dates, by = "day"), .groups = "drop") %>%
  left_join(exposure_df) %>%
  group_by(ids) %>%
  summarize(exposure_sum = sum(exposure_value, na.rm = TRUE),
            na_count = sum(is.na(exposure_value)), .groups = "drop") %>%
  left_join(person_df) %>%
  collect()
```

---

@langtang's approach is clever, by recognizing that the sum over each id's range can be done more efficiently by subtracting the cumulative value at the end of the range from the cumulative value the day before the start of the range. **This improves the time for n=1M to 4 seconds, even using dplyr's slower aggregate calculations.**

```
exposure_df_cuml <- exposure_df %>%
  group_by(zips = exposure_zip) %>%
  transmute(value = exposure_day, 
            expo_cuml = cumsum(coalesce(exposure_value,0)),
            expo_na_cuml = cumsum(is.na(exposure_value))) %>%
  ungroup()

person_df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(ends_with("dates")) %>%
  mutate(value = value - if_else(name == "start_dates", 1, 0)) %>%
  left_join(exposure_df_cuml) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("expo"), ~if_else(name == "start_dates", -.x, .x))) %>%
  group_by(ids, zips) %>%
  summarize(across(starts_with("expo"), sum), .groups = "drop")
```

Comment: I don't think this dtplyr will use gforce for those particular queries, so there is possibly still a lot of time to gain.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get the runtime for one million ids down to a couple of seconds.

The trick here is to use cumulative sums across the entire range of days, and then subtract the cumulative sum at the end date for an id from the cumulative sum at the start date for an id. This is quite fast, because it doesn’t require any expansion of rows and apart from the direct merge, doesn’t require any grouping by ids:

Step 1: Create the cumulative sum of exposure values (`cval`) and number of `NA` values (`nas`)

```
exposure_dt[order(exposure_day), `:=`(
  cval=cumsum(fifelse(is.na(exposure_value),0,exposure_value)),
  nas = cumsum(is.na(exposure_value))
  ),exposure_zip]
```

Step 2: Simply melt the `person_dt` frame, and do direct merge on the `exposure_dt` frame. Make sure to subtract the exposure value from the cumulative sum if this is a start day and exposure value is not NA; similarly subtract one from `nas` if this is a start day and exposure value is `NA`.

```
k <- melt(person_dt,id.vars = c("ids","zips")) %>% 
  .[exposure_dt, on=.(zips==exposure_zip, value=exposure_day), nomatch=0] %>% 
  .[variable=="start_dates" & is.na(exposure_value), nas:=nas-1] %>% 
  .[variable=="start_dates" & !is.na(exposure_value),cval:=cval-exposure_value] %>% 
  .[order(ids,value)]
```

Step 3: Simply subtract the odd rows from the even rows, and `cbind` the result to the `person_dt`

```
cbind(
  person_dt,
  k[seq(2,.N,2),.(cval,nas)] - k[seq(1,.N,2),.(cval,nas)]
)
```

All of this takes 0.08 seconds on my machine with the original 1000 ids dataset. If I set `n=1000000`, it takes about 1.1 seconds.

Output:

```
        ids start_dates  end_dates  zips  cval   nas
      <int>      <Date>     <Date> <int> <num> <int>
   1:     1  2000-10-10 2001-02-18 45108  3188     5
   2:     2  2000-11-11 2001-04-07 45190  3789     1
   3:     3  2000-03-05 2000-06-27 45117  2917     3
   4:     4  2001-02-04 2001-06-09 45142  2969     2
   5:     5  2000-03-16 2000-07-13 45197  2860     3
  ---                                               
 996:   996  2000-02-21 2000-07-29 45139  4250     2
 997:   997  2000-02-02 2000-07-15 45074  4407     4
 998:   998  2001-07-29 2001-11-15 45139  2686     3
 999:   999  2001-09-10 2001-12-20 45127  2581     1
1000:  1000  2000-10-15 2001-05-01 45010  4941     2
```